# Extracting Javascript Variable Object Data in Python and Beautiful Soup Web Scraping

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I can currently scrape Javascript data from a post request I sent using  requests then Soup. But I only want to scrape the product plu, sku, description and brand. I am struggling to find a way in which I can just print the data I need rather then the whole script. This is the text that is printed after I extract the script using soup. I will be scraping more than one product from multiple post requests, so the chunk idea is not really suitable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataObject = {

platform: 'desktop',
pageType: 'basket',
orderID: '',
pageName: 'Basket',
orderTotal: '92.99',
orderCurrency: 'GBP',
currency: 'GBP',
custEmail: '',
custId: '',
items: [

                {


                        plu: '282013',
                        sku: '653460',
                    category: 'Footwear',
                     description: 'Mayfly Lite Pinnacle Women&#039;s',
                     colour: '',
                     brand: 'Nike',
                     unitPrice: '90',
                     quantity: '1',
                     totalPrice: '90',
                     sale: 'false'
                }                                                       ]

};
```

As you can see it is far too much information.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

1. You assign the captured text to a new multiline string variable called "chunk"
2. Make a list of keys you are looking for
3. Loop over each line to check if the line has a term that you want, and then print out that term:

   ```
   chunk = '''
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var dataObject = {
   .........blah blah.......
     plu: '282013',
     sku: '653460',
     category: 'Footwear',
     description: 'Mayfly Lite Pinnacle Women&#039;s',
     colour: '',
     brand: 'Nike',
     ..... blah .......
     };'''

   keys = ['plu', 'sku', 'description', 'brand']

   for line in chunk.splitlines():
     if line.split(':')[0].strip() in keys:
       print line.strip()
   ```

Result:

```
plu: '282013',
sku: '653460',
description: 'Mayfly Lite Pinnacle Women&#039;s',
brand: 'Nike',
```

You could obviously clean up the result using similar applications of `split`, `strip`, `replace`, etc.

Comment: That does work, but I will be extracting multiple products so the names will change ect. If that makes sense

Comment: In your terms, is "name" a key in my list of `keys`? or the text after the colon for each key?

Comment: Can I send you the full script to have a look at? may help you understand what the problem is. Thanks for helping!